# Haskell: How to match a function pattern with recursively types?

Tags: haskell

I have this type recursively:

```
data Expr = Add Expr Expr | Num Int

add (Add (Num a) (Num b)) = a + b
```

For `add Add ((Num 1) (Num 2))` works, but how can I do for all recursively types, like:

```
add Add( (Add (Num 1) (Num 2)) (Num 3) ) ?
```

Comment: How do you evaluate `add (Int 5)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have no way of knowing just how deep a value of your Expr type nests, you have to write a recursive function to evaluate it rather than trying to take on the entire expression at once.

For your Expr type, it would look something like this:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Add a b) = eval a + eval b
eval (Num a)   = a
```

In general, when you have a recursive type like this, you're going to need a recursive function to do anything really interesting with it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer!